# Include custom php functions via theme inside a wordpress page

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, pdo, themes

I would like to include my **custom PHP files**, that are placed outside of my theme, inside of a simple page.

For this I've created a custom theme and register my function in **function.php** as a shortcode with "**add_shortcode()**".

The result is, that all regular PHP commands like **echo "Test";** are working well with this method. 
But as soon as I try to call a function, the script stops.

Also, in the page editor of wordpress I receive always the error message "**updating failed**", but I can still save the changes.

*Note: The selected page includes only the shortcode block with the shortcode name, nothing else.*

Here is my PHP function. Perhaps somebody has the same issue and might know, how to fix this?

**The custom templates functions.php:**

```
//Creates the Result Shortcode
function includeFile() {
    include_once( 'wp-content/php/search_plz.php' );
}

add_shortcode('Result', 'includeFile');
```

**dbmanager.php:**

```
$host = '***';
$database = '***';
$username = '***';
$password = '***';
$pdo = null;

try{
    $pdo = new PDO("mysql: host=$host;dbname=$database", $username, $password);
    $pdo->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
}catch(PDOException $e){
    echo "Error: {$e->getMessage()}";
}

class Users
{
    function getUsers($location){

        global $pdo;

        $users = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM doctors WHERE plz=?");
        $users->execute([$location]);
        $result = $users->fetchAll();

        return $result;
    }

}
```

**search_plz.php:**

```
<?php include('wp-content/php/dbmanager.php'); ?>

<?php

    $input = $_GET['input_location'];

    echo "TEST: {$input}"; //Until here it is working. 

    $users = Users::getUsers($input); //Here the script dies.

?>

<p>Result: <?php echo "in \"".$input."\" "; ?> Location.</p>

<?php foreach($users as $rows): ?>
    <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
        <div class="card-header">
            <h4><?php echo "Name: {$rows['firstname']}, {$rows['lastname']}" ?></h4>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
            <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

And my wordpress page:

```
[Result]
```

Comment: why you are doing this?Use the native wp functions to query the db

Comment: Why are you creating your own PDO connection? Use the already established WP connection: [$wpdb](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb).

Comment: You're also _wide open_ for [XSS (Cross-site Scripting) attacks](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_(XSS)) and should encode the user input before echoing it on the page.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson thanks for your advice. What if i need to access some information from an other database, instead of the wp_database? Will it work with the native wordpress functions? 

And is this the reason, why my own pdo structure didn't work inside of a page? If i access the file directly, and insert the get parameter, everything works well.

Comment: Ah. If you're querying another DB, then I get why you're creating another connection. Btw, if you want to call the method like this: `Users::getUsers($input)`, you should make that method static. Calling non-static methods statically has been deprecated in PHP since a few versions back. It will still work, but it will throw a deprecation warning.

Comment: You should also do some debugging. See exact where in the method it fails. You should also check your web servers error log. There might be some error messages in there that will help you?